# Why do I get an error on response content variable?

Tags: app-inventor

I wanted to create an where in I could retrieve using sql select query from my own web server and wanting it to put it on a listpicker. Any advice or tips? I've tried something and I got an error the operation select list cannot accept the arguments [!DOCTYPE], [5].

Here are my blocks.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please first [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)... you might want to edit your question then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

display the `responseContent` in a label, also use **Do it** to debug your blocks, see also tip 4 here
[Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)

[image]

see also the [App Inventor - MySQL interface](https://puravidaapps.com/mysql.php)

---

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)

Comment: Sorry im just new here, and also a beginner in app inventor. 
after following your advise, i've got a new error here. 

https://imgur.com/a/dHifd

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum, but a Q&A site, you might want to _take the tour again_ how it works... you might want to edit your question instead... see also my edited answer... and: **do the tutorials to learn the basics**

Comment: Sorry for that :) thanks for the advice btw, im just really having a hard time with my project sorry :(